# javascript - (object) is is not defined

Tags: javascript

I got a class (SiteLoader) that one of its properties is another class(LocalStorage_Helper).

I'm testing the small API I made, but I'm getting "LocalStorage_Helper is not defined" error, and I have no idea why.

Here is the class that uses LocalStorage_Helper and the parts that are using the object:

```
/// <reference path="localSotrageHelper.js" /> // -- refrence to the js file

function SiteLoder(_storageName) {
  this.theList = new Array();
  this.storageHelper = new LocalStorage_Helper(_storageName); --HERE is where i get the error
}

//Add_theList_ToStorage
SiteLoder.prototype.Add_theList_ToStorage = function () {
  this.storageHelper.AddItem(this.theList);
}

//Get_theList_FromStorage
SiteLoder.prototype.Get_theList_FromStorage = function () {
  this.theList = this.storageHelper.GetItem();
}
```

I'm using SiteLoader like so, on the html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="SiteLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var Loader = new SiteLoder("sites"); // Error is thrown when i open the html

    function setStoregeTest() {
      Loader.PupolateListFrom_UL("list");
      Loader.Add_theList_ToStorage();
    }

    function showStoregeTest() {
      Loader.Get_theList_FromStorage();
      Loader.WriteListTo_UL("list");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="list" contenteditable="true">
  <li></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="set" onclick="setStoregeTest()" />
  <input type="button" value="get" onclick="showStoregeTest()" />
</body>
</html>
```

- Why I do get an error?
- Do I need to initiate LocalStorage_Helper in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not including LocalStorage_Helper.js in your html markup.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="LocalStorage_Helper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="SiteLoader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: oh, so even if i make a refrence to it in the js file, i still need to link it in the html file?

Comment: That reference in that file has nothing to do with JavaScript. That is something your editor is using for intellisense?

Comment: yeah that make sense, im using visual studio. is there a way to refrence js files inside other js file, so i wont need to linked them inside the html?

Comment: Not with JavaScript. You can look into libraries like require.js or make a build system that combines javascript files.